# Cannot add role="navigation" to wp_nav_menu()

Tags: nav

I would like my custom nav menu to have an attribute "role" with value of "navigation". It does not appear that wp_nav_menu() accepts an attributes argument. Am I missing something?

```
<nav role="navigation">...</nav>
```

Answer (score 4):

Was looking for a while but then saw that you can set 'container' to false.

```
<nav role="navigation">
<?php
  $defaults = array(
    'container'       => false,
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>'
  );
  wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
?>
</nav>
```

Returns a simple navigation without divs in the middle.

Comment: I like this solution. It's clean.

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but here is how to do it:

```
<?php
echo strip_tags( wp_nav_menu( array(
    'echo' => false,
    'items_wrap' => '<nav role="navigation">%3$s</nav>',
) ), '<a><nav>' );
?>
```

Comment: This is still a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my way to do these:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', function( $nav_menu, $args ) {
    if( 'primary' != $args->theme_location || 'nav' != $args->container )
        return $nav_menu;

    $class      = $args->container_class ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $args->container_class ) . '"' : ' class="menu-'. $menu->slug .'-container"';
    $id         = $args->container_id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $args->container_id ) . '"' : '';
    $search     = '<'. $args->container . $id . $class . '>';
    $replace    = '<'. $args->container . $id . $class . ' role="navigation">';
    return str_replace( $search, $replace, $nav_menu );
}, 10, 2 );
```